# NLU Analyze: does the -1 to 1 Sentiment Score for Keyword/Entity represent Magnitude or Confidence?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-tools, watson-nlu

Using the NLU Analyze for Entities and Keywords, the response returns the following Sentiment item score: *Sentiment score for the concept ranging from -1 to 1. Negative scores indicate negative sentiment, and positive scores indicate positive sentiment.*

Does this score represent the magnitude of the positive or negative sentiment (i.e. -.9952 is very negative while -.1301 is sort of negative)? OR Does this score represent the confidence of the positive or negative sentiment (i.e. -.9952 is definitely negative while -.1301 only probably negative)

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#entities https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#keywords https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#sentiment

Answer (score 0):

The score represents the magnitude of the sentiment. In addition to the links you referenced, I found this [Redbook on the IBM Watson NLU (Natural Language Understanding) service](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248398.pdf) quite interesting. It is linked off the additional resources in the [NLU docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/index.html#about).